# Why is this not working?[linklist]

Tags: c, linked-list, typedef

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<alloc.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *n_next,*next,*p_pre,*pre;
};

int main()
{
    node *head,*p,*q,*r,*s;
    head=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p=head;
    q=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    r=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    s=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf(" \nEnter the data of the node ");
    scanf("%d",&p->data);

    printf("\nEnter the data for second node ");
    scanf("%d "&q->data);

    printf("\nEnter the data for third node ");
    scanf("%d "&r->data);

    printf("\nEnter the data for fourth node ");
    scanf("%d ",&s->data);
    getch();
    return(0); 
}
```

After compilation,the code is expected to to take 4 data values and store them in the data field of the respected nodes,but it says..

> scanf("%d",&p->data);     //  Illegal use of pointer???? How is that so?

What part of the code is broken and should be fixed?

Comment: You have not given a typedef name for `struct node`.

Comment: so what should be specified instead?

Comment: @DanielFischer yup,fixed! thnks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typedef is wrong, it should be:

```
typedef struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *n_next,*next,*p_pre,*pre; 
} node; // <---
```

And you're missing commas on some calls of `scanf`:

`scanf("%d "&q->data);`